# re-run perl cpan automatic config

Tags: perl, config, sudo, cpan

This might be trivial for someone deep into perl: how can I re-run the automatic config of cpan on mac? I have chosen 'local::lib', however just recognised I should have chosen 'sudo'. How can I re-configure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within `cpan`,

```
o conf init
```

---

Alternatively, delete `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` (after backing it up, preferably).

---

Alternatively, from within `cpan`,

```
o conf makepl_arg                   ''
o conf make                         '/usr/bin/make'
o conf make_arg                     ''
o conf make_install_make_command    'sudo /usr/bin/make'
o conf make_install_arg             ''
o conf mbuildpl_arg                 ''
o conf mbuild_arg                   ''
o conf mbuild_install_build_command 'sudo ./Build'
o conf mbuild_install_arg           ''
```

Comment: Thanks, I could re-run the config, but it does not ask for the 'sudo' option anymore... I would like to install modules for all users